# How to print log in C#?

Tags: c#

I am building winform application and when I debug my application, I don't see anything on the Local and Call Stack windows, I tried using Debug.writeLine() but nothing is showing from those 2 windows.

Comment: FYI: `Debug.WriteLine` outputs to the...... `Output` window. `View > Output`

Comment: What is the build configuration you are using? You should use 'Debug', make sure you have not selected the 'Release' mode.

Comment: Something is wrong in the configuration, what build type are you using ?

Comment: where to check the build configuration?

Comment: Ya, I can open and see the output window, but when I run debug, the output window is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Trace.WriteLine()` in `System.Diagnostics` Namespace.
[Trace.WriteLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx)

Comment: Try Debug->Windows->Output
Now you should see output window.

Comment: Ya, but the output window is gone when I press debug :(

Comment: Oops, nevermind, I can open the output window in debugging mode as well

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** you need to follow the **trace and debug process in Visual C#**.

Here is a very good [**intro and demo**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)  on how to trace and debug. In addition, i will place just a small quote from article regarding the content of this intro.

> This article describes how to use the Debug and the Trace classes.
>   These classes are available in the Microsoft .NET Framework. You can
>   use these classes to provide information about the performance of an
>   application either during application development, or after deployment
>   to production. These classes are only one part of the instrumentation
>   features that are available in the .NET Framework.